# detect lost connection of a Java FTP client

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm using Java FTPClient class from commons-net to download large files from an ftp server.
I want the file to restart downloading from a certain offset if I detect some connection failure like: my client connection goes down or my server close the connection.
With `client.retrieveFile(filename, out)` I don't get any exception if I close my client connection while I'm downloading the file, the program just freeze there without downloading or doing anything. How can I trigger this events? I saw an FTPConnectionClosedException, but it's only called when the server closes my connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep some kind of sequence id which can represent how much data has been downloaded and set it to some special value once you are legitimately finished.

```
sequence=0;
try{
while(notDone){
   n = client.retrieveFile(filename, out); //bytes read
   sequence =+ n;
}finally{
if(sequence != SPECIAL_VALUE){
    throw new customException();
    }
}
```

Ultimately your code will execute finally block and you can decide how you want to handle it. Or if you want a more `fail fast` solution you can use timeouts by measuring when was `sequence` last updated.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ftpClient.getState()` in paralel therad periodically while downloading goes on. It throws SocketTimeoutException, if connection is gone. Also, previously you need set timeout (Five seconds for example) by `ftp.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(5)`

This is sample:

```
ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(5);
Callable<Boolean> downloadTask = () -> {
    try {
        return ftpClient.retrieveFile(name, counterOutput);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
};
Callable<Boolean> connectionCheckTask = () -> {
    try {
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            ftpClient.getStatus();
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Logger.error("Connection is broken", e);
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Logger.error(ex.getMessage, e);
        return false;
    }
};
ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Boolean result = execSvc.invokeAny(Arrays.asList(downloadTask, connectionCheckTask));
execSvc.shutdown();
```

I don't think that it's the perfect solution, but it works for me.